# Showing $F(x) = \int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log(t)}dt$ is not bounded on $[2,\infty)$ - Proof critique

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

This is question 10 from Chapter 18 of *Spivak's Calculus*. It asks to show that $F(x) = \int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log(t)}dt$ is not bounded on $[2,\infty)$.

The following is the solution I came up with:

**Attempt**

To show that $F(x)$ is not bounded on $[0,\infty)$ means that I have to show there exists an $x \in [0, \infty)$ for all $M>0$ s.t $|F(x)| > M$.

Starting with $F(x)$, observe that

$$F(x) = \int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log(t)}dt = \int_{2}^{x} \log'(\log(t)) dt$$

So by the Fundamental Thm of Calculus II:

$$F(x) = \log(\log(x)) - \log(\log(2))$$

Therefore:

$$|F(x)| > M \Rightarrow\ |\log(\log(x)) - \log(\log(2))| > M$$

after a little algebra we obtain

$$x > e^{e^{M + \log(\log(2))}}$$.

Thus as long as $x$ is greater than this value this will illustrate the function being unbounded.

2. Now another solution I saw which appears simpler is simply:

$$ \int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log(t)}dt > \int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt = log(x) $$

and $\log(x)$ is not bounded on $[0,\infty)$.

I was just curious if my solution is also valid even if it isn't as "pretty?"

Comment: $F(x) \ne \log(\log{x}) - \log(\log{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression of $ F(x) $ is false.

In fact, the derivative of $$x \mapsto \ln(\ln(x))$$

is

$$x \mapsto \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$$

You can prove that
$$(\forall x\ge 2)\;\; \;\ln(x)\le 2\sqrt{x}$$

thus

$$\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\ln(t)}\ge \int_2^x\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}}=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: True.....In that case there isn't an easy way to rewrite $\frac{1}{\log(t)}$. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @dc3rd Take a look at what we call Bertrand's integrals.

Comment: The notion is so advanced that there isn't even a wikipedia entry on it...lol, unless it is related to Bertrand's Theorem....

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental Thm of Calculus cannot be used in this form because $$\lg '\lg x\not=(\lg\lg x)'$$ In the task, it is enough to note that $$(\forall x\ge 2) \ \lg x\le x$$ therefore $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\lg t}\text{dt}\ge\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\text{dt}\:\xrightarrow[]{x\to\infty}\:\infty$$ so from the definition of the limit it follows that for every $M>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $x>N$ there is an inequality $F(x)>M$. Therefore, $F$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

$\int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^n} dt/log(t)
\gt 2^{n-1}/(n\log(2))
$
and the sum of these
diverges moderately violently.